# Travelling to a country from a country other than your home one

Tags: air-travel, tourist-visas

Consider the following situation:

She is from Poland so she doesn't need a visa to enter Singapore as a tourist. She is currently visiting India on a tourist visa.

Question: Can she go to Singapore from India without going back to Poland?

Comment: While this certainly won't *prevent* entry, an important point to consider in such alterations to journeys is travel insurance. Those usually have fine print that will exempt cover for flights other than the first and last one in a multi-leg journey.

Comment: This is perfectly normal activity, there's nothing unusual at all in travelling between countries without returning to your place of residence. I think I've been to nine countries in the last four weeks none of which have been my own. Border control rarely ask where you've come from (except the Americans), all they want to know is when you'll be leaving.

Comment: @Ordous That is terrible travel insurance, you need a new insurer. Who is saying this?

Comment: @Calchas Pretty much every UK bank I've seen (checked 4 major ones) as well as the best corporate health/travel insurer here. They do cover accidents etc, just not the actual flights. Guess it would vary wildly between countries though, and may not be applicable for TI from Poland.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, of course.  There are four main requirements:

- You'll need a flight from India to Singapore.  That's easy to find - I did that with Air India in August, and there are a ton of other airlines that do that.
- visa requirements - as mentioned, a visa is not required.
- a flight OUT of Singapore already booked, as they may want evidence that she is actually planning on leaving Singapore.
- a valid passport, which I assume she has, as she's travelling in India.

Comment: Who is 'they' in the third requirement you mentioned?

Comment: @user135988 Singapore authorities / airline staff.

Comment: @MarkMayo In which cases is an onward or return ticket required? The immigration authorities state in the entry requirements that a ticket is required 'if applicable' without specifying what they consider applicable: http://www.ica.gov.sg/page.aspx?pageid=95

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: it's applicable in most cases.  Examples where an onward ticket would typically not be required include (1) foreigners entering the country for work who have already obtained In-Principle Approval, and (2) arrival in a foreign-registered motorcar or private sailing vessel.

Comment: One additional point to bear in mind - a lot of Indian tourist visas are single-entry. She will need to have a multiple-entry visa for India if she needs to get back in to India again before going home.

Comment: The only thing I'd worry about is peculiar rules or arbitrary application of border officer power in Singapore. I have heard of people being denied entry to Singapore for reasons that seem peculiar, but I don't know that just entering from India is one of them.

Comment: @Dronz "Hippie-type" long hair, mustaches, and beards used to be grounds for arbitary refusal in Singapore.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Yep that was one of the things I heard.